# Python - API - XML

Tags: python, xml, api, python-2.7

I am trying to extract information out of the open weather api, currently i am trying to use

```
import requests

print "enter a city"
city = raw_input()
print "enter a country"
country = raw_input()

fh = open('/home/Ricky92d4/weather.txt', 'w')

info = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+ city +','+ country +'&mode=xml')
fh.write(info.text)
fh.close()

fl = open('/home/Ricky92d4/weather.txt')
new_city = fl.read()

fl.close()

for line in new_city:
    if line.startswith ('<'):
        new_city = new_city.replace('<', '')

    if line.endswith ('>'):
        new_city = new_city.replace('>', '')

    if (line.startswith('?')):
        new_city = new_city.replace('?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?', '')

    if (line.endswith('/')):
        new_city = new_city.replace('/', '\n')

print new_city
```

Is there a quicker way to remove the unwanted information from the api, such as just take out the weather and the location?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `xml.etree`? https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = None
with open('/home/Ricky92d4/weather.txt', 'r') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f.read())
```